# How to store a varying size arraylist in a numpy array (for clustering purposes)?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, multidimensional-array

```
 a=[]
 for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
               cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
               a.append(eyes)        
               i+=1
 print(a)
```

eyes is the detection output from detectMultiScale using eye_cascade (detecting inside a face, but ommitted).

Let's say (ex, ey, ew, eh) are 4 coordinates that need to be stored in an array for each iteration of this loop.

**The output for each iteration looks like this: [54, 46, 90, 103]
But sometimes, it also looks like this: [[20 34 56 41], [34 56 78 89]]**

Sometimes the value of (ex, ey, ew, eh) can be upto 4 array values of in one array.

How can we store these multidimensional outputs in a numpy array?
It does not have a fixed size, sometimes, it is an array of 4 coordinates; sometimes it is an array of an array of many sets of 4 coordinates.

Comment: Best stick with the list

Answer (score 0):

Collect them into a list and then concatenate:

```
>>> out = []
>>> for i in range(5):
...     out.append(np.squeeze(np.full([i, 4], i))) # squeeze to make it more difficult
... 
>>> out
[array([], shape=(0, 4), dtype=int64), array([1, 1, 1, 1]), array([[2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]]), array([[3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3]]), array([[4, 4, 4, 4],
       [4, 4, 4, 4],
       [4, 4, 4, 4],
       [4, 4, 4, 4]])]
>>> np.r_[('0,2,1', *out)]
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4],
       [4, 4, 4, 4],
       [4, 4, 4, 4],
       [4, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Here we use the "magic" concatenator `r_`; its first argument `'0,2,1'` means: concatenate along axis `0`, make everything `2`D, if axes have to be added the preexisting dimensions start at axis `1`., so `[1, 1, 1, 1]` is reshaped to `[[1, 1, 1, 1]]` before concatenation.